# Enotfound exception when sending a Get request

Tags: node.js, rest

These are what the headers look like in Insomnia:
[image]

On the left are request headers and on the right are response headers. And I wrote following code for this:

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
    hostname: 'https://www.sahibinden.com/',
    path: '/get',
    headers: {
        "X-Origin-DC":"gytp",
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "103.255.4.53",
        "X-Client-SrcPort": "45244",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
        "X-TLS-Version": "771",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "ISTL-REFERER":"https://www.sahibinden.com/"

    }
}

https.get(options, (response) => {

    var result = ''
    console.log(response.headers);
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        result += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
        console.log(result);
    });

});
```

It gives me following error:

```
events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://www.sahibinden.com/
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:64:26)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'https://www.sahibinden.com/'
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of `hostname` in `options` to `www.sahibinden.com` (remove `https://` and slash (`/`) at the end. Also, change `path: '/get'` to `method: 'get'`, you probably meant to use `method` instead of `path`. `path` is used for specifying the rest of the URL path after the host URL.

You can also specify `port` in options as `443` (as a replacement for `https`), but since you're using `https` module, `port: 443` is the default.

Comment: It is working but it isn't giving me headers. {
  location: 'https://www.sahibinden.com/guvenli-e-ticaret',
  connection: 'close'
}
This is the output that I get

Comment: And when I put this: 'www.sahibinden.com/guvenli-e-ticaret' in hostname it gives the same error again

Comment: yeah, what you're trying to do can be achieved by having these option properties set as follows: 
`'method': 'GET',
  'hostname': 'www.sahibinden.com',
  'path': '/guvenli-e-ticaret',`

Comment: i will add these to the original answer